# How to create variable length UTF-8 string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, random, utf-8, generated

I am looking to create a variable length UTF-8 string in PHP. I tried this method initially:

```
utf8_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(256, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM))
```

But it gave me a string longer than 256 chars

I then tried this method:

```
md5(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM))
```

Which works for a  32 character long string but if I want a 256 long string I need to concatenate it 8 times which seems inefficient.

How would I do this efficiently in PHP? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I want to be able to generate a 256 character utf8 string and I dont know how to do this in PHP

Comment: You don't need to use `utf8_encode()`, you just need to make sure your file has the encoding `utf8 without bom` and you tell the browser the encoding is utf8.

Comment: could you please elaborate? If I use mcrypt_create_iv(256, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM) it creates a string that has characters that are not in utf8. Is there a way to change this in php?

Comment: Your `header` and actual document are probably not set to UTF-8.

Comment: @KVohra95: Are you trying to create a random string of 256 characters? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with the cryptographic functions.